# Populate a vector<char> in an old fashioned (and dirty) way

Tags: c++, vector, stl, memcpy

I need to violently write into a vector (to avoid superfluous `memcpy`).

Let's consider this very simplified piece of code

```
unsigned read_data ( char * buffer , unsigned maxsize )
    {
    const char * data = "Hi folks! I'm the data" ;
    unsigned size = strlen( data ) ;
    if (size > maxsize) return 0 ;
    memcpy( buffer,data,size ) ;
    return size ;
    }

void main ()
    {
    std::vector<char> v ;
    v.reserve( 50 ) ;
    unsigned size = read_data( v.data(),v.capacity()) ;
    v.force_actual_size( size ) ;
    }
```

Here is the way I imagined : the data is actually written into the vector, but the vector's size is still 0.
So I need this `force_actual_size` method...

Is there a way implement it, or better, a clean way to do the same thing.

And *of course*, `read_data` comes from an old fashioned API I can't modify.

Comment: `resize` instead of `reserve` (and `size()` instead of `capacity()`)?

Comment: force_actual_size is resize.

Comment: @manni66: As OP uses it, you would overwrite the data by `'\0'`.

Comment: What is the motivation for this? Are you trying to avoid double initialization?

Comment: @Jarod42  read_data doesn't care about '\0'.

Comment: @manni66: I meant that replacing `v.force_actual_size( size );` by `v.resize(size)` would erase data written by `read_data`.

Comment: Actually not : with `size` instead of `capacity`, and `resize` before **and** after the call to `read_data`, it works fine !

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::vector::resize` to allocate the memory you require and also correctly update the vector's size:

```
std::vector<char> v;
v.resize(50);
const auto new_size = read_data(v.data(), v.size());
v.resize(new_size);
```

Comment: @Jarod42: whoops, fixed.

Comment: Maybe add some explanation why the OP's version didn't work? I think that would be helpful.

Comment: It works ! I only regret the superfluous initialisation to zero of the whole vector at the first `resize` (of course, in the real life, my data is strongly bigger than 50 bytes).

Comment: @Captain'Flam: if you need that level of fine-grained control, consider creating your own abstraction over a non-zeroed resizable buffer.